# Specifying the destination for the pdf output when using pdflatex, from gVim

Tags: windows, pdf, vim, latex, pdflatex

I am generating a pdf output with `pdflatex` with the following command in gVim:

```
:!pdflatex %
```

This command in turns executes the following in the Command Prompt:

```
cmd.exe /c pdflatex /testvim.tex
```

---

Now, the problem I'm having with this is that the pdf is outputted to the `system32` folder:

```
C:\windows\system32\testvim.pdf
```

**How can I instruct `pdflatex` to generate the pdf in the folder where the `tex` file resides?**

Answer (score 1):

What about using the latex plugin for vim?
http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/

Comment: latex-suite is a great plugin for anyone who frequently writes LaTeX documents in Vim. `:TTarget`, then enter `pdf`, then, in normal mode, type `\ll` to compile to PDF, then `\lv` to view the file . If you always want to generate PDFs, put `let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = "pdf"` in your `.vimrc` (`_vimrc`) file.

Answer (score 0):

This depends mainly on your LaTeX version. Do you use MikTeX or TeXLive ?

The `pdflatex` command of **MikTeX** has a command line option for specifying the output directory and the auxiliary directory (for .aux files).
I don't have MikTeX installed on my PC now, but you should be able to figure it out when running `pdflatex --help` or `pdflatex /?` from the command prompt.

If you are using **TeXLive**, you can first switch to the wanted output directory, then run pdflatex with the full path to your latex input file. This outputs **everything** into the current working directory, including temporary tex files.

I would suggest that you write your own `runpdflatex.bat` file which includes the correct call to pdflatex so you don't have to bother with it every time you want to compile your latex file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you start GVim per Icon?
I do the following:

1. Opening Dos Box
2. Change to my tex-directory cd\local\tex\make
3. gvim foobar.tex
4. Executing :!pdflatex % creates the PDF document in local\tex\make not in the system32-folder